# Disable VSTS automatically updating bug status to "done" when accepting a PR

Tags: azure-devops

When we accept a PR with some bug items attached, VSTS will change the status of those bugs to "Done". This is not really good for our workflow, as we would the bugs' status to change to "Ready for QA", and only the QA engineer would set it to "Done".

How can I change workflow so that the status is not set to "Done" whenever a PR is accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you complete the PR just unchecked the checkbox "Complete linked work items after merging".

[image]

(The state will not change to Done, but will not change also to Ready for QA)

Comment: Thanks. Can you change the default setting of this box?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/

Answer (score 2):

When you complete the pull request， there is an option to Check **Complete linked work items after merging** to complete any linked work items.

However, when you selected this, VSTS will only auto change the work item status to **done**.

We do not have the ability to be able to specify the work item state after it is completed to something, other than Done.

There has been a related uservoice, and you could vote up it, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion:

> **Customize Work Item State after PR is closed**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20166982-customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed

Comment: Thanks. Can you change the default setting of the "Complete linked work items after merging" checkbox?